# Run Ktlint for all modules by executing single task command

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradlew, ktlint

I have multiple modules in my android project. I have one Gradle file which having code for ktlint. I applied that Gradle file to every module by writing this in the project Gradle file.

```
subprojects { subProject ->
    apply from: "$project.rootDir/commonFiles/gradleScript/kotlin-code-quality.gradle"
}
```

now the problem is I can run ktlint on each module by giving their name in command like this.

#### Running ktlint for cache module.

```
./gradlew :cache:ktlint
```

but I need to run all modules ktlint at once.

Here is my [open-source repository](https://github.com/happysingh23828/Android-Clean-Architecture/tree/feature/code_quality_checks) and [pull request](https://github.com/happysingh23828/Android-Clean-Architecture/pull/6) on which I need to perform ktlint action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, it's my bad. `./gradlew ktlint` will always run on multimodule. I had some lint checks fail in the app module. I thought it is running only on the app module.

but when I fixed the app module's lint and ran the `./gradlew ktlint`. it jumped to the cache module.

I hope it helps you Thanks.